# How do I get my garage door to operate when the pull rope was yanked off?

Tags: garage-door

I was pulling out of my garage and the string handle for the door got caught on my roof rack. It pulled the string straight off and now my door won’t open or close. The motor is still running fine, I think it was pulled off track.

How do I put it back on track? I don’t have any tools besides a couple screw drivers.

Comment: Take pictures of anything/everything you think matters or looks odd.

Comment: By "string handle for the door" do you mean the (typically red) emergency disconnect pull cord? If so, it might be that the door is simply disconnected from the opener rail. You should be able to reset the connection by pushing up on the latch that is/was connected to the pull cord.

Comment: Assuming you did not break the "trolley" you should be able to reconnect it by holding the rope end high towrd the garage opening and pulling to reengage the lock on the trolley. At least that is the way my old Genie works.  If you did break the trolly then you will probably have to get a new one. Replacing thst is easy IIRC. Mine wore out and I replaced it. Dose the door open and close manually?

Comment: Good excuse to meet your new neighbors and ask to borrow a ladder.

Comment: Just in case you weren't aware, pulling this rope disengages the "trolly" from the track and allows you to manually raise/lower the garage door. This is quite handy in case your power goes out but you still need to get a vehicle in/out of the garage.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The string activates the emergency disconnect between the chain/belt/cable and the door.

Look for the lever that the string activates and push it back in the in the other direction and run the motor a couple of times the door should reconnect to the moving part.

Then add a shorter string.

Comment: Maybe run the end of the string through a Wiffle ball instead of the standard T-handle. The round ball should be _less likely_ to get caught on things like a roof rack that the T-handle, which forms a nice hook. As an added note, this emergency disconnect is to allow you to raise/lower the garage door by hand should the power be out and you need to get a vehicle in/out of the garage.

Comment: @FreeMan or some kind of teardrop pull handle.  Even something like your wiffle ball with a cardboard cone at the top would minimize the chance of the ball getting caught on the rack.

Comment: I would _think_ a Wiffle ball would be big enough not to get caught under the rack rails, but who knows... It gives a general idea of how to prevent this from happening again in the future.

Comment: I would think it would make more sense to remove any handle completely - a bare string isn't likely to get caught on anything.

Comment: @MikeB yes true, but its harder to grasp when you need to open the door manually (like in a power cut)   On the flip side, its also harder for miscreants to jimmy the door using this release cord if it has no handle.

Comment: @MikeB, you would think that, but have you ever drug a rope, extension cord, or a garden hose across your yard or garage? That sh-tuff gets hooked on Everything and anything. I was going to suggest drilling a hole through a golf ball, then threading the rope through that and tying a knot, but even that might be caught on a roof rack, depending on how high it sits from the roof or, well, just plain bad luck. Look up "ladder golf" if you aren't sure what I'm talking about.

Comment: tie the rope to the door panels so that it does not hang down when the door is open.